# Need help accessing assert bundle file in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to access an XML file that is located in my flutter project's `xmlfiles` directory (I added it to my project directory structure in IntelliJ) and, specifically, access a file within the `xmlfiles` directory called `recipes.xml`.

I'm trying to access it following online examples but am not making progress.

My test method is this:

```
  _loadRecipes(BuildContext context) {
    dataDepot.recipeBook = new RecipeBook();
    var recipesXML = DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('xmlfiles/ingredients.xml');
    print("DUMPING RECIPE BOOK");
    print(recipesXML.toString());
    print("LOADED RECIPE BOOK!!!");
  }
```

When I try runnng it I get this:

> I/flutter (32066): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY
>   ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ I/flutter
>   (32066): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder:
>   I/flutter (32066): The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' was
>   called on null. I/flutter (32066): Receiver: null I/flutter (32066):
>   Tried calling: inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(DefaultAssetBundle)
>   I/flutter (32066): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

...

What I want to do is open the recipes.xml file and parse it, but I first need to open it. Can someone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you add the file to `pubspec.yaml` `assets: ...`? https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/

Answer (score 0):

In you pubspec.yaml look for the section called assets

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
```

This tells flutter that all your application assets are located within this folder.
more info - https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/

IMPORTANT: Make sure you use tab for each line.

Comment: "IMPORTANT: Make sure you use tab for each line."
No tabs are needed. Correct indentation, yes; tab characters, no.

Comment: We're talking about the same thing, I just prefer using tabs because it's easier to be consistent than manually adding spacing which can decrease readability if you aren't consistent..